# Unexpected generic type inference behavior with numerical literals

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create a generic wrapper for any numeric value (à la [micrograd](https://github.com/karpathy/micrograd/blob/master/micrograd/engine.py#L2)) in Swift 5.7. So far I have this implementation:

```
struct Value<Scalar: SignedNumeric>: Equatable {
    
    var data: Scalar
    
    init(_ data: Scalar) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

// MARK: Value+SignedNumeric
extension Value: SignedNumeric {
    typealias IntegerLiteralType = Scalar.IntegerLiteralType
    typealias Magnitude = Scalar.Magnitude
    
    var magnitude: Magnitude {
        data.magnitude
    }
    
    init(integerLiteral value: IntegerLiteralType) {
        self.data = Scalar(integerLiteral: value)
    }
    
    init?<T>(exactly source: T) where T : BinaryInteger {
        if let numericData = Scalar(exactly: source) {
            self.data = numericData
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    static func * (lhs: Value<Scalar>, rhs: Value<Scalar>) -> Value<Scalar> {
        return Value(lhs.data * rhs.data)
    }
    
    static func + (lhs: Value<Scalar>, rhs: Value<Scalar>) -> Value<Scalar> {
        return Value(lhs.data + rhs.data)
    }
    
    static func - (lhs: Value<Scalar>, rhs: Value<Scalar>) -> Value<Scalar> {
        return Value(lhs.data - rhs.data)
    }
    
    static func *= (lhs: inout Value<Scalar>, rhs: Value<Scalar>) {
        lhs.data = lhs.data * rhs.data
    }
}
```

The **issue** that I'm having is that the code below doesn't compile if I only provide an integer literal without any explicit type annotation:

```
func testScalarTypeInference() {
    // all of these compile fine
    Value(Double(1.0))
    Value<Double>(1)
    Value<Int>(1)
    Value(Int(1))
    Value(1 as Int)
    Value(1.0)

    // doesn't compile
    Value(1)  // Generic parameter 'Scalar' could not be inferred in cast to 'Value'
}
```

Why does the compiler infer the type of a simple `Double` literal (`Value(1.0)`) but not an `Int` literal (`Value(1)`)?

**EDIT**: I've forgot to mention the most confusing part. This issue only exists while the `Value` is trying to conform to `SignedNumeric`. The following code compiles fine:

```
struct ValueWrapper<Scalar: SignedNumeric> {
    var data: Scalar
    
    init(_ data: Scalar) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

func testValueWrapperTypeInference() {
    type(of: ValueWrapper(1))    // Expression of type 'ValueWrapper<Int>.Type' is unused
    type(of: ValueWrapper(1.0))  // Expression of type 'ValueWrapper<Double>.Type' is unused
}
```

So I assume there might be something wrong with one of the `init`s perhaps?

Comment: You should not call: `init(integerLiteral:)` directly. From [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral/init(integerliteral:)-7jqe8) **Do not call this initializer directly. Instead, initialize a variable or constant using an integer literal.**

Answer (score 2):

It's actually simpler than SignedNumeric. The same problem exists for ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral (which SignedNumeric requires):

```
struct Value<Scalar: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral>: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    var data: Scalar

    init(integerLiteral value: Scalar.IntegerLiteralType) {
        self.data = Scalar(integerLiteral: value)
    }
}


Value(1) // Generic parameter 'Scalar' could not be inferred in cast to 'Value'
```

I don't think it's possible to build what you're trying to build. (It's possible there's ambiguity with the `init(_ value: Self)` extension on ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, which may be why it's calling this a "cast.") I recommend opening a [bug report](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues) if you need this functionality. I don't believe it's possible to create ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral as a generic wrapper because you can't default the Scalar type, and that prevents you from conforming to SignedNumeric.

It is possible that [SR-7476](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/47757) is related.

Comment: "I don't think it's possible to build what you're trying to build.". Yes I will use a `Double` instead of a generic `Scalar` that conforms to `Numeric`. There are only more issues arising from this approach e.g. division. The init ambiguity makes sense.

Comment: Also, Double cannot express all values that Int can express, so it can introduce errors if your range is large. There is discussion of permitting generic defaults, which I believe could fix your problem. Syntax like `struct Value<Scalar = Int: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral> ...`

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the compiler infer the type of a simple `Double` literal (`Value(1.0)`) but not an `Int` literal (`Value(1)`)?

I think because [`SignedNumeric`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/signednumeric) inherited from [`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral) but it doesn't inherit from [`ExpressibleByFloatLiteral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyfloatliteral).

When the compiler sees a literal with a decimal point in it e.g. `1.5`, unless a floating point type can be inferred from context, it assumes `Double` and it can then say `Scalar` must be a `Double` in this case. This is a special case so that people don't have to be explicit about the type of `f` in `let f = 1.5`.

There's a similar rule for integer literals but, unfortunately, it doesn't apply because any `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` overrides the rule, and even if it didn't, if you have two `Scalar` types whose implementation of `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` used `int` as the associated type, you couldn't choose between them.

At least, that's my theory.

Comment: I don't understand: Doesn't `Float` also _overrides_ it's `FloatLiteralType ` ? It is [`Float`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/init(floatliteral:))  not `Double`.

Comment: I've edited my question that sort of disproves this theory. Please have a look or elaborate :)

Answer (score 1):

##### Edit

Indeed it is confusing, and after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75913184/1425697) I tried with a conformance to `ExpressibleByFloatLiteral` and this time `ValueWrapper(1.0)` triggers the error:

```swift
extension ValueWrapper: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral where Scalar: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral {
    init(floatLiteral value: Scalar.FloatLiteralType) {
        self.data = Scalar(floatLiteral: value)
    }
}

struct ValueWrapper<Scalar: SignedNumeric> {
    var data: Scalar
    
    init(_ data: Scalar) {
        self.data = data
    }
}
func testValueWrapperTypeInference() {
    type(of: ValueWrapper(1))    // Expression of type 'ValueWrapper<Int>.Type' is unused
    type(of: ValueWrapper(1.0))  // Generic parameter 'Scalar' could not be inferred in cast to 'ValueWrapper'
}
```

So I think it is more plausible that the issue comes from some *ambiguity with `init(_ value: Self)`*.

##### Original Theory

If you look at [`ExpressibleByFloatLiteral.FloatLiteralType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyfloatliteral/floatliteraltype):

> ##### Discussion
>
> Valid types for FloatLiteralType are Float, Double, and Float80 where available.

But for
[`ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral.IntegerLiteralType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/expressiblebyintegerliteral/integerliteraltype) you have:

> ##### Discussion
>
> The standard library integer and floating-point types are all valid types for IntegerLiteralType.

ie. when you initialize a floating point from a literal it can only be a floating point, and the default is `Double`, but when you use a integer literal it could either be an integer or a floating point and the compiler is confused.

Comment: I've edited my question by adding a "counter example" where I'm able to initialize it from both literal types.

Comment: after reading to [Rob Napier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75913184/1425697) answer. I tend to agree with him. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why is failing (may be a conflict with some other language features or other constructors), but if you change the call from `Value(1)` to `Value.init(1)` it starts working. Another workaround is to use named parameter in the constructor `Value(data: 1)`. Or type it like this:

```
let v: Value = .init(1)
```